# Package hyperref destroy \leftmark and \rightmark with KOMA

Tags: hyperref, header-footer, koma-script

I noticed, when I use `\usepackage{hyperref}` the left and right marks are destroyed. One can verify this by uncommenting `hyperref` in `MWE` below.

---

**Without `hyperref`**
[image: Without <code>hyperref</code>]

---

**With `hyperref`**
[image: With <code>hyperref</code>]

```
\documentclass[oneside,
           a4paper,
           parskip=off,
           12pt]{scrbook}


%\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@part}{\@mkboth{}{}}{\@mkboth{#1}{#1}}{}{} %
\makeatother

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\cohead[]{\leftmark}    
\cohead[]{\rightmark}
%\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\begin{document}
\part{One}
\lipsum[1-20]
\part{Two}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

How can I prevent this undesirable behavior?
Or, how to insert headers, which is contain a part title in `KOMA scrbook` simultaneously using `hyperref`?

Comment: `hyperref` is usually loaded last.

Comment: Of course, there are exceptions, like `glossaries`. `scrlayer-scrpage` should be loaded before `hyperref` and you are fine.

Comment: @Johannes_B Thank you, I'll remember this rule for hyperref.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) does a lot of behind-the-scenes work in order to make hyperlinks work correctly inside a document. As such, it typically stores existing commands for usage later, and updating the definitions according to its requirements.

In your specific case, `\@part` is not the macro to be patched when you are using `hyperref`. Instead you need to patch `\H@old@part` - made by `hyperref` to store the "old" version of `\@part`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[oneside,
           a4paper,
           parskip=off,
           12pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\H@old@part}{\@mkboth{}{}}{\@mkboth{#1}{#1}}{}{} %
\makeatother

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\cohead[]{\leftmark}    
\cohead[]{\rightmark}
%\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\begin{document}
\part{One}
\lipsum[1-20]
\part{Two}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

You would have also picked up that your `\patchcmd` is not work as expected in you added `\tracinpatches` to your preamble and checked your `.log`:

```
[debug] tracing \patchcmd on input line 13
[debug] analyzing '\@part'
[debug] ++ control sequence is defined
[debug] ++ control sequence is a macro
[debug] ++ macro can be retokenized cleanly
[debug] -- search pattern not found in replacement text
```

The search pattern `\@mkboth{}{}` is not found, since `hyperref` redefined `\@part` to be

```
\def\@part{%
  \ifnum\Hy@secnum@part>\c@secnumdepth
    \phantomsection
  \fi
  \H@old@part
}
```

The alternative, as with most things related to `hyperref`, would be to load it last.

Comment: Since `hyperref` should be loaded last, hyperref will use the patched macro.

Comment: @Johannes_B: Yes, I've added that to my answer. I first wanted to address the reason why it doesn't/didn't work.

Comment: Got my upvote with that addition ;-)

Answer (score 5):

You could use the KOMA-Script command `\automark` and redefine `\partmarkformat` to get the desired result:

```
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\automark[part]{part}
\renewcommand\partmarkformat{}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[oneside,
           a4paper,
           parskip=off,
           12pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\automark[part]{part}
\renewcommand\partmarkformat{}

\begin{document}
\part{One}
\lipsum[1-20]
\part{Two}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, this more laconic solution. Thank you! And I have another problem with koma. Did you know how to assign empty pagestyle to all toc pages only (in KOMA)?

Comment: Only in the table of contents or also in the list of tables etc? Can you open a new question?